# Angular 2/5 - Passing form data between components using service

Tags: angular, forms, behaviorsubject

I have a form with multiple inputs and select menus etc and I'm trying to populate another form in another sibling component using it's values.

I've managed to accomplish it using just a single hard coded staring by the below code but how do I do it using the values that are entered into the initial form?

Here is how I've been trying to achieve it but no luck...

I currently have a service that deals with this called data.service:

```
  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<IQuote>(quote);
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(quote: IQuote) {
    this.messageSource.next(quote);
  }
```

I'm using this interface for the form:

```
export interface IQuote {
  firstname: string;
  surname: string;
}
```

My Initial form HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="quote" (ngSubmit)="post(quote.value)">

  <fieldset>
      <label class="question" for="firstname">First name</label>
      <input ngModel name="firstname" formControlName="firstname" id="firstname" class="textbox" type="text"/>
      <div class="error" *ngIf="firstname.touched && firstname.invalid">Your first name is required.</div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset (mouseenter)="addClass($event)" (mouseleave)="removeClass($event)">
      <label for="surname">Surname</label>
      <input ngModel name="surname" formControlName="surname" id="surname" type="text"/>
      <div *ngIf="surname.touched && surname.invalid">Your surname is required.</div>
  </fieldset>
```

Inital form typescript:

```
quote: IQuote;

post(quote) {

  this.quoteService.create(quote);

  this.dataService.changeMessage(quote);
}
```

The form that needs to be populated:

```
  <fieldset>
      <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
      <input id="firstname" type="text" [value]="quote.firstname"/>
      <div *ngIf="firstname.touched && firstname.invalid">Please select a title.</div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
      <label for="surname">Surname</label>
      <input id="surname" type="text"/>
      <div *ngIf="surname.touched && surname.invalid">Please select a title.</div>
  </fieldset>
```

The typrescript for the form that needs populating:

```
quote: IQuote;

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.currentMessage.subscribe(quote => 
    this.quote = quote);
}
```

Please let me know if you require anything else.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Are you looking for code review, or facing an actual issue

Comment: Way too much code in this post. Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and when you're done take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Haha, thanks for your feedback. Code has been stripped back :)

Comment: you need to use form bindings for forms. look into ngModel or reactive forms

Comment: yeah i've tried that but couldn't figure out how to make it work in the code behind